# Max Value for xorShift128+ (or what's wrong with my implementation)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

I'm reading up random number generators and tweaked an implementation of the xorShift128+ algorithm in javascript.  I understand how bit shift operators work and how the xor bit operations work, though I'm still learning why they're useful, and why their use in xorShift128+ produces a uniform random distribution.

But more to the point, I just need to know what the range of possible numbers it works with is.  It outputs integers, I'm trying to get numbers between 0 and 1.  Inductively, I see that it's in the order of 2**32.  So I use that as the divisor.  However, when I check for uniformity, I notice a bias in the numbers.  They seem to be repelled in the areas of 0.2 <= val < 0.3 and val >= 0.7.

So I've either got the calibrating divisor wrong, I've got my implementation wrong, or I'm confused about the uniformity property.  Any help would be appreciated.  Below is my code and my analysis:

```js
function xorShift128p(seed) {

    // seeds
    this.x = seed || this.x || 1;
    this.y = seed + 1 || this.y || 2;

    // swap seeds
    let x = this.y;
    let y = this.x;

    // bit manipulations that are still a little
    // obscure to me as to why they work well
    y ^= y << 23;
    y ^= y >> 17;
    y ^= x;
    y ^= x >> 26;
              
    // reset seeds
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    // output, with calibration for 0-1 range.
    let realResult = x + y;
    let myCalibration = realResult / (2**32);
    return myCalibration;

}

// produce an array of 100 random numbers using xorShift128p
let rands = 
    [...new Array(100).keys()]
    .map(() => xorShift128p());

// bin the random numbers into units of 0.1 
let binCounts = 
    [...new Array(10).keys()]
    .map(key => 
        `lead: ${(key / 10).toFixed(1)}, ` + 
        `count: ${rands.filter(r => r >= key / 10 && r < (key + 1) / 10).length}`
    );    

// notice the non-uniformity
console.log(binCounts);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xorshift128+, `x` and `y` are supposed to be `uint64_t`. That causes a number of differences between this implementation and the actual xorshift128+:

- The right shifts are arithmetic shifts but should have been logical shifts. I don't know how bad that is, but it's definitely different.
- The final addition is supposed be modular, but here it is a (floating point) double precision sum. That's very bad.
- There aren't 128 bits of state. This makes the PRNG less strong but in a way that is non-trivial to detect.

The final sum not being modular makes the result *non-uniform* and with a different range than the scale factor assumes: the sum of two IID numbers in [-2<sup>31</sup> .. 2<sup>31</sup>-1] (the result of using Number instead of `uint64_t`) is in [-2<sup>32</sup> .. 2<sup>32</sup>-2] and biased towards numbers of smaller magnitude. That's the same kind of effect as the sum of two fair die rolls. This could be worked around by adding `>>> 0`, but then the code still would not implement xorshift128+.

Fixing the fundamental issue would be a bit painful, requiring the 64bit integer operations to be emulated. There are some libraries that can do that job for you.

Comment: Okay, lots to go on here.  Seems I may be misunderstanding symbols in what I've been reading or in what Javascript does.  Like, I thought I was doing logical shifts with `<<` and `>>`, so I'll have to look into how that's not the case.  And I didn't realize that the `+` in what I was reading was supposed to be some sort of modular addition.  I would have expected to see a `mod` or `%` somewhere.  Thank you very much.

Comment: JavaScript numbers (until recently) correspond to Java's `double`, and have 53 significant bits of precision.  They don't behave like 64-bit integers.